# Postgresql multi-field index on jsonb data does full tablescan when field is not found

Tags: postgresql, index, nosql

I have a table with millions of records.  I need to query for the last-added record by timestamp, for a given field.  Pretty simple stuff, trivial to do with SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE records
(
    id integer,
    "timestamp" integer,
    type text
);
CREATE INDEX idx_type_time_sql
ON records (type ASC, timestamp DESC);
```

Queries are fast, even searching for a type that does not exist in the table.

```
select * from records where type = 'KNOWN' order by timestamp desc limit 1
select * from records where type = 'UNKNOWN' order by timestamp desc limit 1
```

I can also almost get it working with NOSQL (aka a jsonb field that contains all object properties):

```
CREATE TABLE records
(
    id integer,
    json jsonb NOT NULL
)
CREATE INDEX idx_timestamp
ON records (((json->'timestamp')::bigint));
```

This is fast (a few ms) to find a record when type is found.  However, THIS FAILS to use the index if the type is not found in the table.  It does a full tablescan that takes 12 seconds or so.

```
-- fast:
select * from records where json->>'type' = 'KNOWN'
order by (json->'timestamp')::bigint desc limit 1;
-- slow:
select * from records where json->>'type' = 'UNKNOWN'
order by (json->'timestamp')::bigint desc limit 1;
```

I have tried many different types of jsonb indexes and queries with no luck, eg:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_type_timestamp ON records ( (json -> 'type'), ((json -> 'timestamp')::bigint));
```

Is there any way to get postgresql jsonb indexing working as well as a good old fashioned SQL index, when querying for unknown values?  Or is this just a shortcoming of jsonb?

Comment: An index over `->` can't be used for a condition over `->>`.  The operators need to match. Once you build the correct expressional index, make sure you ANALYZE the table so you get stats on it.

Comment: I consistently used `->` for timestamp.  I also tried many combinations.  Nothing completed the query quickly when the where clause did not hit successful results.

Comment: "I consistently used -> for timestamp"  But not for 'type', which is slightly important here.

Comment: I tried that and it only gets worse.  I'm not sure how to show all the work I've tried to get this going.  I guess I'll update the question with more examples that fail.

Comment: Aha - i got it working with your nudge, @jjanes - I'll post an answer with the details - thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paying close attention to matching the index syntax with the query syntax was all that was needed to solve this (thanks @jjanes).  Once you do, the successful approach is very similar to indexing standard SQL columns.

Index:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_json_pair ON records ((json->>'type'),((json->'timestamp')::bigint));
```

Now, both hit and miss queries are fully indexed and fast:

```
select * from records where json->>'type' = 'KNOWN' order by (json->'timestamp')::bigint desc limit 1
select * from records where json->>'type' = 'UNKNOWN' order by (json->'timestamp')::bigint desc limit 1
```